# Can you use an mysql @variable in WHERE IN (SELECT @var)?

Tags: mysql

Can you use an mysql @variable in WHERE IN clause  ?

I tried this:

```
SET @inlist =   
(    
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_id) FROM products WHERE `status` = "new"    
);

SELECT @inlist;  -- shows comma separated values;

SELECT * from products where product_id IN (SELECT @inlist);
```

will only return the first product in the list.

I know there is a default 1k limit on GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Because your example makes no sense. You don't need any variables for that. And no you can't use MySQL session variables that way.

Comment: why use the variable when you can use the query directly in the `where` clause? `select * from products where product_id in (select product_id where status='new')` (if you want to waste time in the subquery)

Comment: `@inlist` is a string, it's not an actual list of values.

Comment: I know I don't NEED to do this. I wondered if I could. I was in an interactive session, not a program and I keep having to paste a list which made me raise this possiblity.

Answer (score 2):

try this with [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
    SELECT * from products where FIND_IN_SET(product_id , @inlist );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with dynamic SQL:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT * from products where product_id IN (', @inlist, ')');
EXECUTE stmt;
```

If you need to do this frequently, you could put it in a stored procedure, and then just do:

```
CALL yourProc(@inlist);
```